# Split string into list with two different delimiters

Tags: python, list

For this, I would like to split the s string into 4 different parts, with it turning out like this:

```
['19', '00', '00', 'AM']
```

I am having trouble currently trying to get the AM part separated, though. Here is what I have so far.

```
s = "19:00:00AM"

def timeConversion(s):
    for x in s:
        timetype = s.split(":")
        print(timetype)

timeConversion(s)
```

Comment: If the string is fixed format, probably just take another step of processing. But your code has some other problem too.  Thinking to use `re` module?

Comment: You should use module `datetime` to parse dates and times. If not, then `re`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
s = "19:00:00AM"
res = s.split(":")
print(res)
x = res.pop()
m = (x[-2:])
n = x[:-2]
res.append(n)
res.append(m)
print(res)
```

Comment: You don't need regex to split on colons

Comment: Thanks, made the edit. 